# Subfolders not getting created in MacOS as they should

Tags: python, macos

I had a piece of code, that was creating folders and subfolders really well in Windows. However the same piece of code is not creating the folders as it should. Instead of creating the folders, and the subfolders, it creates folders with the names as the path of the subfolders. e.g. If the main folder is Execution, and subfolder name should be Client1, and inside it I wanted a folder called Webservices, it will create three folders,

1. Executions
2. Executions\Client 1
3. Executions\Client 1\Webservices

Can anyone please suggest what i need to change. The code is given below.

```
folder = create_execution_folder(w_exec_id.value)
exec_id, webservice_path = folder
stage = set_environment_stage(w_override_folder.value, webservice_path)
stage,override,process_dict_stage = stage
process_dict.update(process_dict_stage)

sub_folders =create_execution_sub_folders(exec_id,webservice_path,stage)
       
compare_path,dm_compare_path,rtf_compare_path,analysis_compare_path,process_dict_folders    = sub_folders

process_dict.update(process_dict_folders)

run_file = os.path.join(webservice_path, 'run_exec.py')
f= open(run_file,"w+")
f.write('stage_run_exec = "%s"' % stage)
f.write("\n")
f.write('exec_id_str_run_exec = "%s"' % str(w_exec_id.value))
f.write("\n")
f.write('webservice_path_run_exec = r"%s"' % webservice_path)
f.close() 
sys.path.append(webservice_path+'/')
```

Comment: Please re-check the code you posted. It includes non-code like `your text`, has bad invalid indentation (Stack Overflow takes first four spaces to mean "this is code"), and notably does not contain any part that actually creates folders. I suspect the missing pieces are in the method `create_execution_sub_folders`, which you have not included here. With that, there is no way for us to see exactly what you are doing wrong. But as a guess, you are creating file names manually by joining them with backslashes, instead of using `os.sep`, or better yet `os.path.join`.

Comment: Mac OS uses `/` instead of \ as its path separator. So e.g. it should be `Executions/Client 1` rather than `Executions\Client 1`

Comment: I would recommend updating your code to use `pathlib` instead of `os`. `pathlib` will handle your paths in an OS agnostic way, so you don't have to handle switching between \ and / yourself.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety `os.path.join` will do that too.

Answer (score 2):

MacOS and Windows represent(and parse) paths differently. In Windows, a path would look like `\path\to\foo`, while in MacOS, it would be `/path/to/foo`.

If you try to parse a string targeted towards Windows, it will create a folder with the whole string. In MacOS, it will create a folder with the name `"\path\to\foo"`.